# Test the render method in a controller with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am trying to test the render method in a controller with RSpec (2.x).
Here the code in my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @entities, :include => :properties, :overview => options[:overview] }
end
```

And here the test I try in my spec file:

```
controller.should_receive(:render).with( hash_including(:overview => true) )
```

The problem is that RSpec tells me that no arguments are provided for render ("got: (no args)"). Not even the :json one. How do I stub the render method correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to test your `render :json`, just check that the response does contain a JSON string.

Simplified example: `response.body.should == @object.to_json`

If you just want to stub render method use `controller.stub!(:render)`